# SQL Server: Show similar rows with a number in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, grouping

I want to get the third column as given below from sql. I had used `DENSE_RANK()` but that does not serve the purpose as i want the series as follows:

```
A 90    1
B 85    2
C 85    2
D 80    4
E 75    5
F 75    5
G 75    5
H 70    8
```

Comment: Use `RANK` instead of `DENSE_RANK`

Comment: that works ... Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with rank:

```
select t.*,
    RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY t.value  desc) AS rank_id
from(
    select           'A' as id, 90 as value    
    union all select 'B' as id, 85 as value    
    union all select 'C' as id, 85 as value    
    union all select 'D' as id, 80 as value    
    union all select 'E' as id, 75 as value    
    union all select 'F' as id, 75 as value    
    union all select 'G' as id, 75 as value    
    union all select 'H' as id, 70 as value   
) as t
```

results:

```
id  value rank_id
A   90      1
C   85      2
B   85      2
D   80      4
F   75      5
G   75      5
E   75      5
H   70      8
```